# Update / concatenate a column value with another column value for same type of record with different id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
create table #test
(
    id int, 
    section char(2), 
    seq int, 
    caseID int, 
    Modal varchar(10), 
    value1 varchar(10), 
    value2 varchar(10), 
    CustName varchar(10), 
    donedate datetime
);

insert into #test 
values (1035, 'A1', 902, 408, 'Ind', 'firstTime', 'valtyp1', 'templerun', '2020-10-23')
insert into #test 
values (1035, 'A1', 903, 408, 'Ind', 'secondtime', 'valtyp2', 'templerun', '2020-10-23')
insert into #test 
values (3144, 'A1', 901, 801, 'Ind', NULL, 'valtyp1', 'templerun', '2020-10-23')

select * from #test
```

**Returns**

```
+------+---------+-----+--------+-------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  id  | section | seq | caseID | Modal |   value1   | value2  | CustName  |  donedate  |
+------+---------+-----+--------+-------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1035 | A1      | 902 |    408 | Ind   | firstTime  | valtyp1 | templerun | 10/23/2020 |
| 1035 | A1      | 903 |    408 | Ind   | secondtime | valtyp2 | templerun | 10/23/2020 |
| 3144 | A1      | 901 |    801 | Ind   |            | valtyp1 | templerun | 10/23/2020 |
+------+---------+-----+--------+-------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Here I'm trying to updated Value1, value2 columns with other row/record of same type. Example:

- in 1st row: value1 = 'firstTime secondtime' & value2= 'valtyp1 valtyp2'
- in 2nd row: value1 = 'secondtime firstTime' & value2= 'valtyp2 valtyp1'

Where 'seq' has different values.

Can someone please explain me how to write a query to concatenate/update one row with another row for same column.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can match rows on `caseID` and `seq` is different you can self join the table with an `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET value1 = t1.value1 + ' ' + t2.value1,
    value2 = t1.value2 + ' ' + t2.value2
FROM #test t1
INNER JOIN #test t2 ON t1.caseID = t2.caseID
                   AND t1.seq <> t2.seq;
```

Note that this won't update the 3rd row in your table.  Also, this solution would change if you have more than 2 rows with a matching value for `caseID`.